# AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey crash

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am doing real time video recording using AVAssetWriter and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput. I see many crash reports on user devices but can not reproduce it on any of my devices. I need info on what could be going wrong in code below. It happens probably because typecast of NSDictionary to [String:AnyObject] fails.

In the class I have:

```
private var videoOut: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?
```

And then in a function, I do this:

```
  var recommendedSettings:[String:AnyObject]?

  recommendedSettings = videoOut.recommendedVideoSettings(forVideoCodecType: AVVideoCodecType.hevc, assetWriterOutputFileType: AVFileType.mov) as? [String : AnyObject]

  if let recommendedSettings = recommendedSettings {

  /* crashes here */
  var compressionSettings = recommendedSettings[AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey] as! [String:AnyObject]


  }
```

What is the assumed return type for dictionary returned by AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned type is the dictionary, i.e

```
let videoCompressionProps: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
    AVVideoAverageBitRateKey : videoBitrate,
    AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey : videomaxKeyFrameInterval,
    AVVideoProfileLevelKey : avVideoProfileLevel
]
```